# A report to be viewed by a television?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, crystal-reports

We have a system for each of our company branches. It is almost similar to `POS` though it is off on `barcode`. It has several modules and numerous report for each of the menu. Here's the thing, recently our Manager told us that our Big Boss [the owner], would love to view the status report for each of the branches that's directly imported to his device [either television which is connected to the internet or through his laptop].

Now, I believe that this instruction is somewhat possible since the system was on VB.net and the process would require an internet access which present to those devices that I mentioned.

But the only thing that concerns me is the major adjustment.

Is it the system that has to be adjusted for this purpose or it must be the Reports which is obviously in Crystal Report. I am not so great when it comes to VB.net, though I have a background with `PHP&MySQL` since I worked as a Web Developer. I was thinking to incorporate the programming language of `PHP&MySQL` and create a page that will fetched the details for the report needed then try to have additional module embedded with .php (or perhaps an html5) file on the .net system.

But I don't think this would be sound so easy.
And since this "supposed" module is equipped with `PHP` file, it would be easy for our Big Boss to access this separate report at home, whether he used his internet-ready Television or just his laptop.

Any suggestion?

Comment: So whats the problem here?